# Does Safari have a CSS position animation bug?

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

In Safari, I'd like to use CSS to animate between `position: relative` and `position: fixed`. Yes, I know this is a discrete animation. That's what I need.

This works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari. Is this a bug? Is there a way to make this work?
https://codepen.io/z5h/pen/XWmNBgK

Comment: I don't think `position` is a valid property to animate with css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties. Why not just toggle `relative` and `fixed` using javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Formal_definition It has a discrete animation type which is exactly what I need. JavaScript is not an option.